# Calculate width and height of Flv and Swf using C#

Tags: c#, flash, flv, dimensions

I can't work out how to calculate the width and height dimensions of a .flv video or .swf file using C# .NET.

Comment: Have you already using a library to work with flv, or you're asking for a good suggestion?

Comment: haven't used any library yet, I only want to be able to calculate the dimensions, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this article](http://johndyer.name/post/2005/08/Flash-FLV-meta-reader-in-NET-(C).aspx) can help you. It show how to read flv files and it's meta information in c#.

Basically, you have to open a binary file stream and read the first part of the file.

You have than to interpret bytes you read according to [Adobe flv format specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flv.html). 
Anyway, the article has some code sample showing you how to read width  and height of files.